# Regular Expression pattern in

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string full of metadata and want to retrieve just some unique codas with a pattern: A letter + 4 numbers i.e: R0001, D0453, L0465

I'm currently querying this with:

`re.findall(r'\bD[0-9999]*', test_data6)`

And I change the letter for all the alphabet and run the script. Is there a way that it can find all that specific patterns easily?

I tried: `re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+[0-9999]*', test_data6)` but doesn't get quite what I need

Comment: `[0-9999]` is just a really inefficient way to write `[0-9]`. The character class matches a single character; mentioning the same character again does not make it match more characters.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\d{4}\b', test_data6)`

Comment: In short your current `[0-9999]` is saying "I want characters `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and also `9` and `9` and `9` too. Instead `[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```py
import re
s = "D5678 G562 HHJ2 HZ981112"
re.findall(r"[A-Z][0-9]{4}", s)  # ['D5678', 'Z9811']
```

`[A-Z]` will match any upper case letter and `[0-9]{4}` will match any string of 4 numbers from 0 to 9 following each other.

Comment: The `+` in `[A-Z]+` is wrong if they only want to match a single character before the digits.

Comment: Based on the OP's `[0-9999]`, I'm guessing that `[0-9]{1,4}` would be more in line with what they're looking for.

Comment: It looks like the OP is looking for "A letter + 4 numbers"